# ASP.NET MVC ou WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

Qual é vantagem de usar MVC e WebAPI (utilizando Visual Studio e C#)?

Penso que desenvolver em MVC é mais fácil de montar um formulário com validações, pois basta colocar atributos especiais para essa finalidade e usar o Wizard que já monta o formulário automaticamente. O WebAPI não tem esse recurso ou estou enganado? Em que momento usar o WebAPI e/ou MVC?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

São coisas distintas, então não é uma questão de ser vantajoso usar um ou outro. Eles devem ser usados para propósitos diferentes. Apesar que eles poderiam ser usados em conjunto.

Tanto podem que o ASP.NET WebAPI passou ser parte integrante do [ASP.NET Core](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/index.html). Você não usa mais um ou outro porque essencialmente eles têm operações diferentes quando quer fazer uma coisa ou outra (essencialmente a WebAPI não tem *view*), mas a base é a mesma.

O MVC pressupõe que o usuário vá acessar *sites* que são coleções de páginas para visualizar. WebAPI só retorna resultados, ele obviamente não têm visões, o V do MVC.

WebAPI sempre precisou de uma estrutura mais simples, mas se pensar bem elas precisam de modelos (o M) e precisam, se não dos controladores (o C), de algo muito parecido. Por isto faz mais sentido usar um *framework* único.

Trabalhar com WebAPI é mais fácil por uma simples razão, ele faz muito menos. E justamente por isto se você quer apresentar páginas, WebAPI não é uma opção. Pelo menos não sozinho.

Claro que é possível usar WebAPI para pegar os resultados e montar as páginas com outra tecnologia. Mas duvido que isto faça algum sentido para você. Pode fazer para terceiros consumidores da sua API. Por terceiros, entenda outros programadores ou outras aplicações feita por você.

Como o nome diz WebAPI é para criar APIs de acesso nos moldes da *web*. API é para programadores consumirem e como que melhor lhes convier. Não é para construir *sites* inteiros.

Você pode até fazer o formulário totalmente no lado do cliente (tipo [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)). Aí não precisaria do MVC, mas isto não funciona bem para *sites*, funciona melhor para aplicações.

Então WebAPI não monta um formulário para você porque não é seu objetivo.

Acho que neste caso você deve usar MVC.

Ou se for fazer algo mais simples considere ainda [ASP.NET WebPages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) ([ASP.NET Razor Pages melhor ainda](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)). É curioso como quase ninguém conhece isto. Eu vejo muitos programadores se matando para usar ASP.NET MVC para fazer *sites* muito simples, simplesmente porque não conhecem tudo o que existe em ASP.NET. Esta tecnologia permite fazer *sites* de forma análoga ao que se faz no PHP puro usando apenas o que já está sendo disponibilizado por padrão na linguagem. WebPages/Razor Pages dá toda uma infraestrutura que ajuda muito sem impor um modelo de desenvolvimento.

Também considere usar [Blazor do lado do servidor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.0). Evite o uso do ASP.NET MVC clássico usado no [.NET Framework que morreu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A próxima vez que vir um engraçadinho defender MVC com DDD ou coisa do tipo vou passar o link do WebPages, aí ele monta o site inteiro na mão. Ótima recomendação. +1.

Comment: O que é o **WebPages**? Como eu posso criar um projeto do tipo **ASP.Net WebPages**?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho é isso que está no *link*. A pergunta bastante extensa para por em um comentário. É uma forma mais simples de fazer sites web que não demandam grande complexidade. Basicamente você produz as páginas individuais sem muita cerimônia ou modelo de desenvolvimento. É muito livre. Ele tem a *vew* que é quase igual ao ASP.Net MVC. Tem algumas facilidades para manipular o que vem do cliente, para montar o que precisa, mas nada tão pronto como no MVC. Mas é mais flexível e simples de usar. Não impõe um *model*, mas pode ter se quiser. A ligação de tudo você faz como quiser.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho pode começar porque aqui: https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/getting-started

Answer (score 7):

À resposta do Maniero, que considero globalmente correta, gostaria apenas de acrescentar que quando ele diz:

> Claro que é possível usar WebAPI para pegar os resultados e montar as páginas com outra tecnologia. Mas duvido que isto faça algum sentido para você. Pode fazer para terceiros consumidores da sua API.

Diria que não é verdade na situação em que for pretendido utilizar uma FW rica no *frontend* como Angular ou React. Para além disso, quando diz:

> API é para programadores consumir e fazer o que quiser, não para construir sites inteiros.

Também diria que cada vez mais *developers* estão a construir todo o *server-side* com base em Web API (ou qualquer outro tipo de *webservices*). Nesses casos, o *frontend* é normalmente desenhado com recurso a Angular/React.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, eu em minha humilde opinião concordo com Maniero, quando estamos nos referindo ao WebAPI , acredito estarmos unificando uma plataforma de serviços com um acesso global a mesma.

Se constrói uma camada de serviços que N plataformas distintas podem consultar seja uma aplicação web, ou plataforma mobile, ou plataformas de diferentes tecnologias. O fato de estar se montando um formulário usando uma aplicação MVC somente , você estabeleceu um acesso único ao seu formulário e os registros não são compartilhados com outras plataformas.

Caso você deseje ampliar esse seu acesso aos dados de maneira global, uma estrutura WebAPI se faz necessária, tornando assim um acesso único e global, reduzindo o esforço no desenvolvimento de aplicações