# Angular + ASP.NET MVC: Faz sentido?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arquitetura-de-software, angular, typescript

Estou começando a estudar Angular2.

Como estou trabalhando muito com .NET resolvi fazer um projeto com ASP.NET MVC 4 e Angular2.

Dando uma lida no *hello world* do Angular notei que o Angular tem o próprio mecanismo de rotas, o que de certa forma deixaria inútil o mesmo mecanismo do ASP.NET MVC, certo?

1. Faz sentido eu ter uma controller no ASP.NET MVC para exibir
   somente uma *view*?
2. A utilização do ASP.NET MVC, quando utilizado junto com Angular,
   tende a ser a "função" do`WebApi?
3. Do ponto de vista arquitetural, faz sentido eu ter `ApiController` e
   `Controller` dentro do mesmo escopo?

Comment: Um detalhe: Angular2 não é AngularJS.

Comment: Acho que houve uma pequena confusão. ASP NET vai fazer o backend, então as rotas do backend serão as rotas dos serviços localhost/rest/usuario/cadastro que receberá um json *(ou xml ou o que preferir) para fazer a persistência no banco. No frontend o angular terá sua rota localhost/site/usuario/cadastro onde será exibida a página html com o formulário bonitinho para o usuário preencher, com o javascript do angular validando o form...

Comment: Mas ele quis dizer sobre usar o ASP.NET MVC mesmo, não WebApi @BartolomeuS.Gusella

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faz algum sentido. Uma coisa não elimina a outra. Se faz muito sentido aí já é questionável. Talvez seja mais importante o ASP.NET WebAPI.

Se sua aplicação tiver realmente uma única página o ASP.NET MVC será bem pouco útil, ele só gerará uma página. Mas essa página fará inúmeras requisições de informação para o servidor, e o normal seria respondê-las com o tal do WebAPI.

Se estiver usando o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) aí nem precisa se preocupar porque o [MVC e o WebAPI virou uma coisa só](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52158/101).

Tem uma pergunta que fala sobre as [tecnologias web do .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111209/101).

Tem outra pergunta que [compara o uso do MVC com SPA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130973/101).

E finalmente há uma pergunta que fala sobre o [WebAPI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/49094/101).

Note que essas rotas do Angular2 e as rotas do ASP.NET MVC não possuem relação direta. Um executará no cliente (navegador) e outro no servidor. São propósitos diferentes. Uma tecnologia não concorre com a outra, elas são complementares.

Obviamente que as rotas do Angular2 vão acabar levando para rotas do WebAPI. As rotas do Angular2 podem funcionar de forma totalmente independente. Se consegue resolver tudo no cliente, ele não pede nada para o servidor. Quando ele precisar de algo do servidor uma requisição será feita, aí as rotas do WebAPI entram em ação no servidor para determinar o *controller* adequado a chamar e fornecer o que precisa.

Entenda que o uso do Angular2 é para minimizar o acesso ao servidor, não pense nas duas tecnologias como algo que forma uma coisa só, são coisas distintas. Inclusive se fizer certo e um dia quiser trocar o Angular2 pelo React ou outra tecnologia, é para conseguir sem mudar nada no servidor. O servidor nem precisa saber que você está usando Angular2.

> Faz sentido eu ter uma Controller no ASP.NET MVC para exibir somente uma view?

Para a página eu acho que não faz muito sentido, faz ter o *controller* para o WebAPI.

> A utilização do ASP.NET MVC, quando utilizado junto com angular, tende a ser a "função" do WebApi?

Exatamente.

> Do ponto de vista arquitetural, faz sentido eu ter `ApiController` e `Controller` dentro do mesmo escopo?

Até faz sim, se usar o MVC, obviamente que não faz se não usar o MVC. Se usar o .NET Core nem precisa se preocupar com isso.

Considere o uso de [Blazor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288706/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: [...] Um executará no cliente (navegador) e outro no servidor [...]. Big, não há diferença no caso específico de direcionamento e exibição de `views`, há?

Comment: @MarllonNasser não entendi sua dúvida.

Comment: Eu acho que eu não estou conseguindo entender a diferença entre as rotas executadas no cliente e no servidor. Eu preciso dos dois? Um só não basta? Não consigo entender o propósito da rota do mvc **junto** da rota do angular2.

Comment: @MarllonNasser Precisa dos dois. Editei pra ver se fica mais claro

Comment: Ok, big.. ficou mais claro. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

> Faz sentido eu ter uma Controller no aspnet mvc para exibir somente
>   uma view?

Sim, você consegue usar os dois, mas na minha visão, **não, não faz sentido algum** usar MVC com aplicação SPA - seja angular, react, *whatever*.

Se analisar um pouco, verá claramente dois problemas - acredito que vc já os enxergou, por isso que veio aqui perguntar.

1. A camada de *VIEW* do MVC, usando Razor, irá "conflitar" com suas views do Angular. De cara vc nota que um não combina com o outro, ou que não há necessidade de coexistirem.
2. **Arquiteturalmente** também não é saudável. Todo projeto web deve ser pensado de forma **Cloud First**. Sua aplicação web front-end - angular - deve ser independente da sua aplicação web back-end - ASP.NET. Assim vc pode hospedar e escalar sua aplicação web de forma/dinâmica diferente. Sem uma depender ou estar hospedada dentro da outra.

> A utilização do aspnet mvc, quando utilizado junto com angular, tende
>   a ser a "função" do WebApi?

Pois é, não faz sentido usar MVC, e sim apenas ASP.NET WebAPI. Pois se usar MVC, isso diz que vc terá que carregar todas as libs e dlls referentes à *Views*, como as libs de Razor, Optimization, WebPages, etc. E vc não irá utilizar nada disso. Então se é um projeto WebAPI, não carregue nada de MVC, deixe seu projeto mais leve.

Mesmo no ASP.NET Core, se for usar apenas como WebAPI, vc não precisa adicionar dependencias à recursos de View.

> Do ponto de vista arquitetural, faz sentido eu ter ApiController e
>   Controller dentro do mesmo escopo?

Se vc for criar uma aplicação MVC, e de dentro da sua View quiser fazer apenas requisições REST, faz sentido sim. Mas se for segregar isso em uma aplicação web SPA, e o backend for apenas uma API RESTful, então não há necessidade, é até melhor remover como explicado acima.

Answer (score -1):

Olá,

Para mim faz sentido ter as 2 tecnologias juntas. 
Conteúdos que você gostaria que fossem indexados pelo Google precisam ser renderizados no server, logo, o MVC ajudaria nesse ponto.
Áreas do sistema (website) que não tem necessidade  de indexação, é interessante usar SPAs.

Comment: Se puder esclarecer um pouco mais acho que vai ajudar quem fez a pergunta