# WebAPI x WebServices

Tags: .net, aplicação-web, web-service, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

WebAPI foi criado para substituir de melhor forma um WebService? Caso não, qual a diferença exata entre os dois e quando usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Da uma olhada nesses sites, eles fazem uma comparação bem interessante sobre a diferença entre os modelos de serviços web que temos.

https://codigosimples.net/2016/02/25/differenca-entre-wcf-wcf-rest-web-api-e-web-service/

http://netcoders.com.br/wcf-web-api-estudo-comparativo/

Na minha opinião, eu considero que uma WebApi é também um tipo de Webservices porém baseado em Rest.

O cenário WebApi Rest é mais simples de se implementar e se você quiser disponibiliza-lo para uma grande variedade de clientes (celular, website, etc) essa é a solução mais prática no meu ver!

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/121998)

Comment: Verdade @Renan fiquei com medo de copiar a resposta de outros sites por causa de direitos, você não vê problemas?

Comment: Fazer uma citação de um trecho de uma página não viola direitos autorais pelas legislações do Brasil, da Europa e dos países da América do Norte, então acho que você está bem coberto pela lei. Só não esqueça de linkar a fonte.

Comment: Valeu @Renan muito obrigado pelas dicas ;)

Answer (score 9):

Não, WebAPI é para criar [*web services*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90315/101). Ele usa uma técnica [RESTful](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45783/101) para comunicar pontos de interação. *Web service* é uma técnica geral, WebAPI é uma tecnologia específica da Microsoft para lidar com *web services*. Quando você usa WebAPI está fazendo um *web service*, então não há dicotomia entre eles.

No [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) ele nem é uma tecnologia separada do MVC (veja mais em algumas perguntas como [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111209/101), [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49090/101) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52158/101)).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: @bigdown, não compreendi, o WebAPI não foi criado para substituir o WebService, mas sim para criar WebServices, Por mais que seja apenas uma tecnologia Microsoft, pra quem mexe apenas com ela, é mais viável criar uma WebAPI do que um WebService certo ?

Comment: O que seria um WebService que é diferente de um web service? Tem link pra ele?